# Does "Spider-Man: Far From Home" contain more spoilers to "Endgame", except this?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, spider-man-far-from-home

I want to take a friend to watch the movie. He did not watch *Avengers: Endgame* yet.

Except for the obvious

> that Spider-Man is alive again,

are there any other spoilers to *Endgame*? Since he already figured the first one out, is it okay to see *Spider-Man: Far From Home* first?

Comment: How about the **big one** --- that a certain couple of characters DIE?

Comment: Several: Snape kills Dumbledore, Rosebud was his sled, and Vader is Luke's father.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Spider-Man: Far From Home* is the final film for Phase 3 and deals with the fallout of *Avengers: Endgame* as quite a major plot point, I would highly recommend watching *Endgame* beforehand.

For spoilers that are mentioned in *Far From Home* for *Endgame* the obvious major one that you haven't listed is:

> Tony died and Peter is dealing with his grief over him.

On top of that we have:

> - All of Peter's friends are back - they were snapped
> - An in memorium video to the lost Avengers: Steve, Tony and Nat
> - That the Avengers won and beat Thanos and returned the world to "normal"
> - The five year gap

There are a few other minor references and "spoilers" but I think they are the main ones to be wary of.

---

FWIW before watching *Far From Home* [I would recommend](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/101898/45378) watching *Captain America: Civil War*, *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, *Avengers: Infinity War*, *Avengers: Endgame* and potentially *Iron Man*. These films are quite good for dealing with the Spider-Man storyline and the Peter/Tony relationship that is key to *Far From Home*. You might not fully understand what is going on in each of them without watching some other films but if you are only bothered about the *Spider-Man* side of things that shouldn't be 100% needed.

Comment: Note that Steve is not actually dead - he's just retired and no longer 'Cap'.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Hence why I said "lost" Avengers.

Comment: Also the five year gap itself. Maybe I'm in the minority, but I remember that being a huge WTF moment for me personally in Endgame. I always thought they'd bring everyone back so that was no real surprise, but I'd absolutely expected a straight continuation of events with minimal time between the snap and the return, so that five years of people dealing with the pain was a big deal for me.

Comment: @delinear Good point added it to the list

Comment: Not critical, but you won't understand the stinger if you haven't seen Captain Marvel.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there's a huge major one, so major Tom Holland had to come out before one of the trailers and warn of spoilers for Endgame:

> Tony stark is dead.

Then there's the fact that:

> Not only Spider-Man is back from being snapped, but also Strange, Fury, Hill, and a few others.

Literally right out the gate of the movie (not even 5 minutes into it):

> The "Blip" is also a big spoiler. We all knew it was going to happen, but the idea that everyone came back is technically a spoiler for Endgame. Plus it also showed roughly how they came back, which is also a spoiler.

Those are the big ones off the top of my head, but I should also mention another big one that @TheLethalCarrot's post reminded me of:

> Several main Avengers are dead.

Also, very minor one in comparison, but technically still a spoiler:

> Thor's still alive, but not on earth anymore.

So those are the big ones.

In short, for anyone who reads this, don't watch Spider-Man Far From Home if you haven't seen Endgame, or really, *really*, **REALLY** don't care about it being spoiled for you. Even still if you choose to watch this before Endgame, you'll still probably regret having it spoiled for you later.

Comment: FFH doesn’t tell us Thor is off Earth does it?

Comment: Yup. Maybe it only said he was "unreachable," but it was at the same time when Spider-Man asks Fury if he has anyone else.

Comment: Pretty sure he's referred to as Off World in the scene where SpiderMan meets Mysterio for the first time

Comment: @Chipster "Unreachable" was for Doctor Strange (_not_ Mister Strange)...